# How to get image to be a solid white instead of a translucent white?

Tags: html, css

I have two images that essentially need to be on top of each other. The logo is somehow stuck being an opaque white instead of the solid white my client wants it to be. How do I fix this?

HTML & CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PALPA | Tunes for the Toasties</title>
</head>
<style>
    body{
        background-image:url("../img/background-min.JPG");
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
    #palpa_white{
        height: 550px;
        width: 490px;
        margin-left: 240px;


    }

    .center_container{
        height: 580px;
        width: 1000px;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.7;
        margin-left: 22%;
        margin-top: 9%;
    }


</style>
<body>
    <div class = "center_container">
            <img src = "../img/palpa_white.png" id = "palpa_white" alt = "kael_logo">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Image of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4MK9.jpg)

Comment: what is the purpose of `opacity: 0.7`?

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS specifies `opacity: 0.7` for the `center_container` div. Therefore, the child `img` tag also inherits this 70% opacity.

You need to override the opacity for the `#palpa_white` style.

```
    #palpa_white{
        height: 550px;
        width: 490px;
        margin-left: 240px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to change `opacity: 0.7;` to `opacity: 1;` in the `#palpa-white` style section. Here's a demo of this:

```css
.body {
border-radius: 10px;
max-width: 500px;
height: 300px;
margin: 0.01em auto;
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0ba360 0%, #3cba92 100%);
}
h1 {
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
}
body {
background: #121212;
font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
}
.body #before {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
background: #ffffff;
max-width: 250px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0.01em auto;
opacity: 0.7;
border-radius: 10px;
}
.body #after {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
background: #ffffff;
max-width: 250px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0.01em auto;
opacity: 1;
border-radius: 10px;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background: #121212;
 border: none;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image:  -webkit-linear-gradient(-20deg, #fc6076 0%, #ff9a44 100%);
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>Before</h1>
<div class='body'>
  <div id='before'>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>After</h1>
<div class='body'>
  <div id='after'>
  </div>
</div>
```